# DevOps OffBoarding - SSL Certificate Issue

Tags: ssl-certificate, devops

A devops person setups a server, installs SSL cert and apps.
He/she would therefore have access to SSL cert and its private key.
How should he/she be off-boarded in a way so that SSL cert is not misused by him/her afterwards?
Should this be part of some contract or should the cert be renewed?
What is the best way such cases are handled in organizations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would like to share my candid response in a manner that I deem fit. These are just my personal views.

A DevOps engineer is an integral part of any technology company, which is nurtured with trust and longevity. In terms of safety & security, they know all the weaknesses of the Development team (code) - and possible ways it can compromise the system. SSL is a very tiny piece in the big picture. One should be concerned for N number of other possible vulnerabilities in their system.

Every DevOps engineer chose to be one - because they love how cloud computing and the complexity of a secure network. They religiously ensure security & safety of the entire system 24X7 - in their best capacity. We value associations over petty money/disputes - and we lead an ethical life and not just act ethically on the work front. To add to this - I being one myself - I know how much effort, hard work, dedication and most importantly Time is required to gain client’s trust - I would never imagine throwing all my life work, just like that.

Coming back to a possible solution to your problem - pick up a team or an individual whom you TRUST - ask them to revisit the entire network and secure any vulnerabilities, if any. Changing the SSL would be recommended along with resetting all the passwords.